# Android Keystore generation failure with java keytool

Tags: java, android, classpath, keystore, keytool

I ran the command prompt from the directory containing keytool.exe and ran the command line for keystore generation and after accepting all details and beggining to store keystore it ends up showing this error:

```
[Storing CandMKS.keystore]
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: CandMKS.keystore (Access is 
denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: CandMKS.keystore (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1144)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

Now I think the problem is with java. Something to do with java paths because earlier I tried to build with CLI and it gave an error while debugging java with javac. Any suggestions ?

Comment: FileNotFoundException: CandMKS.keystore (Access is denied): try to change the CandMKS.keystrore to another location and run again. Because this file is can not access

Comment: The problem is with the permissions on the file or directory. Nothing to do with Java whatsoever,

Comment: And the solution??

Answer (score 0):

Ran CMD as administrator. Problem solved.